# A set $S$ of positive integers is self-indulgent if $\gcd(a, b) = |a-b|$ for any two distinct $a,b\in S$

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

A set $S$ of positive integers is self-indulgent if $\gcd(a, b) = |a-b|$ for any two distinct $a,b\in S$

(a) Prove that any self-indulgent set is finite.

(b) Prove that for any positive integer n, there exists a self- indulgent set with at least n elements.

For the first question it can be seen that their will be no self indugent set consisting more no of elements twice of minimum element present.
For sake of exploration i have picked any natural number. got its prime factorization. added every possible factors to the original number. it can be seen that for a self indulgent set where any arbitrary no N is minimum all the elements will be got by adding every factor of N initially. then there will be similar process to follow on the natural numbers we get by adding factors of N to N.Then for each of the numbers we will get a set of natural numbers.We will take intersection with all those sets with the first set we got. We can get multiple self indulgent set with minimum element N.

Now help me to proof that there will be a self indulgent set with n elements for any arbitrary natural number N. I can feel it is possible but just can't grasping it.

Comment: Do you mean $|a-b|$?  The gcd will never be negative...   For the second part, I suggest solving it for small $N$ first, look for a pattern in the constructon.

Comment: yes  for 2 numbers i have 2,4  for 3 numbers i have 3 ,4 ,6 for 4 numbers i have 15,16,18 ,20 for 5 numbers i have  20,21,24,25,30 like these

Comment: $\gcd(21,25)\ne|25-21|$. Maybe take smallest element $n$ to be a product of lots of primes, and then see if you can use $n(1+p^{-1})$ for primes $p$ dividing $n$

Comment: There's an answer at https://www.quora.com/If-two-numbers-are-divisible-by-their-difference-is-the-GCD-of-the-two-numbers-always-equal-to-their-difference#:~:text=Is%20it%20always%20possible%20to,distinct%20elements%20is%20their%20gcd.

Comment: @hey Gerry good to here from you and thanks for your suggetion. I overlooked that in case of 21. so it needs to be removed .

Comment: Can you elaborate on you reasoning for "no self indugent set consisting more no of elements twice of minimum element present"? (We can easily make it just $|S| \leq \min S$, so I want to see how you're thinking about it.)

Comment: Hello Calvin. In your set there will always be a minimum number . when you will calculate the gcd with any other number with that minimum number  it shuld be the difference between the two numbers. lets assume you have 15 as minimum number in any set. if you have any number greater than 30 in your set the difference between 15 ,the min number,and that other number is going to be greater than 15 which is the gcd of 15 and that number. so this is a contradiction to have gcd of two numbers greater than any one of them. so in the set consisting 15 as minimum cant have more elements with value 2*15

Comment: actually i said what you said but written in a wrong way. Sorry for that. My mistake

Answer (score 1):

Here is the construction of self-indulgent sets of arbitrary finite cardinality given at quora.com (link in my comment on the question):

Let $a_1,a_2,\dotsc,a_n$ be a self-indulgent list of $n$ distinct positive integers.
Let $L$ be the least common multiple of $a_1,a_2,\dotsc,a_n$.
Then $L,L+a_1,L+a_2,\dotsc,L+a_n$ is a self-indulgent list of $n+1$ distinct positive integers.
For example; $1,2$ is a self-indulgent list, with $L=2$;
$2,3,4$ is a self-indulgent list, with $L=12$;
$12,14,15,16$ is a self-indulgent list, with $L=1680$;
$1680,1692,1694,1695,1696$ is a self-indulgent list of five distinct positive integers (and I'm too lazy to calculate $L$.)

The proof that this works is easy. We have $|(L+a_i)-(L+a_j)|=|a_i-a_j|=\gcd(a_i,a_j)$, and $\gcd(a_i,a_j)$ divides both $a_i$ and $a_j$, so it divides their lcm, which divides the lcm of $a_1,a_2,\dotsc,a_n$, which is $L$. Also, any $d$ which divides both $L+a_i$ and $L+a_j$ divides their absolute difference, which is $|a_i-a_j|$, which equals $\gcd(a_i,a_j)$, so $\gcd(L+a_i,L+a_j)=|a_i-a_j|$.

Comment: $(a,b)\!=\!|a\!-\!b|\!\iff\! a\!-\!b\mid a,b,\ $ and $\ a_i\!-\!b\mid L\!+\!a_i,L\!+\!b\,$ is true by  $\,a_i\!-\!b\mid a_i,b\mid L,\,$ for $\,b\!=\!a_j\,$ (or $\,0)\ \ $

Comment: $L= 343319185440$, according to https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/math/lcm.php

Comment: Length five, with smaller numbers: $72,78,80,81,84$.